# Searching for a High Speed Actuator for a simulator

Tags: hydraulics, building-design, actuator

I am currently planing to build a consrtuction for a simulator.
My simulator seat should be able to fall like 30cm and afterwards move to the starting position .

The falling should be as natural as possible. For that my actuator has to be really fast.
I am searching for a good soultion to lift up the seat with a person like up to 100kg.

I was thinking about a linear actuator or a linear motor.

About the linear monitor I know it is really fast and would probably provide a fast motion.
I wasn't sure, whether it can hold a heavy person at one position.

Any ideas, suggestion and solution or links to good linear motor or linear actuator would be really hepful.
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I'd suggest that you don't rely on the actuator for the falling motion. Use the actuator to lift the seat, then latch the seat in place and retract the actuator back down. Release the latch and the seat falls, then the actuator lifts it back up again so the latch can hold it. This way you don't need the actuator to fall quickly (since it only needs to retract in time for the next fall).

Comment: Thanks that is really good idea and really helpful! Do you know any project which used such kind of latch system ? Would be awesome if you know such kind of project and link it to me!

Comment: The first one which comes to mind is a [Water Dunk Tank](https://www.google.com/search?q=water+dunk+tank&oq=water+dunk&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2943j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) where someone sits on a seat which is held above a water tank using a latch mechanism. Another person throws a ball at a target, and if it hits then the latch is released and the person on the seat gets dunked into the water.

Comment: Another thing that this reminds me of is that carnival ride where chairs are gradually hoisted up a vertical shaft, then released